# Kdb find first not null value

Tags: group-by, kdb, notnull

While doing a Group By In KDB. I have to find the first not null value in that group for a column

For e.g.

```
t:([]a:1 1 1 2;b:0n 1 3 4 )
select first b by a from t
```

I found one way to achieve this is:

```
select first b except 0n by a from t
```

I am not sure if it is a correct way to do this. Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a good way to do it to me.

Two alternatives would include:

```
select first b where not null b by a from t
```

Benefit being it doesn't rely on a certain column type, maybe more clearly explains your intent but it is slightly longer. Or

```
select b:last fills reverse b by a from t
```

Which on some test runs was the quickest way.

In kdb there's always multiple ways to do things and never really a right or wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks John for the reply. I was not aware of the above ways. i ran following queries to see which one works faster                                     <br/>t :([]a:1000000?100;b:1000000?100)
<br/>meta t
<br/>select first b except 0Nj by a from t
<br/>select first b where not null b by a from t
<br/>select b:last fills reverse b by a from t                                                      <br/>Looks like 1st and 2nd query were quick then 3rd. May be there will be scenarios where 3rd one will be a better choice